# Permissões de acesso no Ubuntu em projeto Angular

Tags: angular, linux, ubuntu, permissões

Estou tendo problema de acesso aos arquivos gerados pelo `ng new`. O problema já começa que não consigo executar o comando sem o `sudo` na frente.

Após serem geradas todas as pastas do Angular, a pasta fica bloqueada para meu usuário, fica com um cadeado, sendo que sou o único usuário da máquina.

Ao abrir a pasta do projeto no VSCode e tentar salvar algo sempre aparece um pop-up solicitando que tente como `root` (conforme print anexo).

Já tentei todo `chmod` que vi pelos fóruns de Linux, tentei mudar a permissão do meu usuário no arquivo `passwd` mas nada acontece.

Não sei se fiz algo de errado durante a instalação ou se mudei alguma coisa durante o uso mesmo.

Caso alguém que já teve esse problema e possa me ajudar, fico muito grato.

Obs.: Se acharem que aqui não é o lugar certo de fazer essa pergunta, eu deleto e vou pros fóruns próprios.

Versão do meu Ubuntu: 18.04.2 LTS.

**Edit 1**: já tentei também executar o VSCode como root, mas daí ele vem sem todas as minhas extensões.

[image: Pop-up para permissão no VSCode]

Comment: E se você clicar no `[retry as sudo]` funciona?

Comment: Sim, logo após pede minha senha e vai tranquilo. Mas pensa no trabalho que dá tu ta digitando rápido e tem que salvar, daí clicar na caixa, colocar a senha e quando for ver, esqueceu de um ponto e vírgula no CSS. Daí tem que fazer tudo isso de novo só por 1 caractere... não faz sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **SOLUÇÃO**

Acabei fazendo besteira e tive que reinstalar o Ubuntu. Daí refiz todo o processo de instalação do Node/npm e angular-cli sem usar `sudo`. Agora ta funcionando normal. Consigo criar o projeto, alterar e salvar em real time que não fica pedindo permissão.